# Leaves dissapearing in a binary tree

Tags: c#, encoding, binary-tree, huffman-code

I'm trying my hand at homemade Huffman encoding. I've got the binary tree generation going, if not for a slight flaw.

My leaves dissapear when they get more then one level deep. My root node will have children, but those children will have null for their leaves. I believe this has to do with references not being kept around, but I can't seem to figure it out aftetr two days.

```
    private HuffmanTree fillTree(PriorityQueue<HuffmanTree> _eQueue)
    {
        while (_eQueue.count > 1)
        {
            ///Dequeue children
            HuffmanTree node1 = _eQueue.Dequeue();
            HuffmanTree node2 = _eQueue.Dequeue();

            ///Create new parent
            HuffmanTree parent = new HuffmanTree();

            ///Set up relations
            parent.node_left = node1;
            parent.node_right = node2;
            node1.parent = parent;
            node2.parent = parent;

            ///Give parent the weight of it's children combined
            parent.weight = node1.weight + node2.weight;

            ///Reinsert parent into priority queue
            _eQueue.Enqueue(parent, parent.weight);
        }

        ///Return the last object in the queue
        return _eQueue.Dequeue();
    }
```

This is the code I'm using to generate the Huffman tree.

```
    public HuffmanTree node_left { get; set; }
    public HuffmanTree node_right { get; set; }
    public HuffmanTree parent { get; set; }
    public int weight { get; set; }
    public char value { get; set; }
```

And these are the class variables.

Can you guys help me out?

I've got my project up on github too. You can take a gander if you want.

https://github.com/samynv/HufmanEncoding

All work is done in the Dev branch. The code works fine in the createTree function, but will not work in the compressString function.

Comment: Looks right to me.  How are you observing the state of the tree to determine that it only ever has a depth of 1?

Comment: I'm observing my values with the debugger. The problem intially started when I tried to use my binary tree to encode a string. For some reason it never produced a node with a value. I ran the debugger with local variables and started manually looking into the leaves. After a depth of one it had just dissapeared.

Comment: You should use the debugger to verify that your program is doing what it should be doing, or to see what it's doing if you are unsure.  You shouldn't use it as the primary means of getting the output of your program; the program should do that without the debugger.  Among other problems, if your program never actually observes a value there are all sorts of optimizations the compiler can do to, say, never actually compute it.

Comment: Indeed, what Servy mentions, manually traversing through a tree with the debugger is not always as reliable. Though, in your specific example, I can traverse through it correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I checked your code, and it looks like it should be working. I also ran the code you have on GitHub, and your program correctly builds the tree. The resulting root after your `fillTree` operation has the correct children, multiple levels deep (as opposed to only one level, as you state).

When I check the resulting values and their weights, and cross reference them with this online Huffman coding demo (http://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse373/04sp/fullhuffmandemo.html) I get the exact same weights and leaves when I run your program with your sentence "j'aime aller sur le bord de l'eau les jeudis ou les jours impairs".

Are you sure you are not interpreting your own tree wrong?

Comment: While the actual tree generation was working fine, the problem arises when actaully compressing strings. I started working on that in my dev branch. I think the problem arises in the compressString function, and the values are not appropriately copied when declaring

While in the original CreateTree function the branches are all intact, they are broken as soon as they are entered into the compressString function

Comment: Also, I should've mention stuff goes awry in my dev branch instead of master. My bad.

Comment: I tried to port it from dev to master. It does work now. Not all trees suddenly go to null after two deep. Thanks for the inspection though.